# How to use xpatch to replace some lines of the codes in "blx-caspervector-base.def"?

Tags: biblatex, xpatch

How to use `xpatch` to replace some lines of the codes in `blx-caspervector-base.def` from [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-caspervector/tex), i.e., replace lines 55, 56, 70, 72 by the following codes respectively:

```
andmore = {\bbx@cetext{\bbx@cnetal}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
andothers = {\bbx@cetext{\bbx@cnetal}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},

{\bbx@cetext{\bbx@cnetal}{\mkbibemph{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}},

{\bbx@cetext{\bbx@cnetal}{\mkbibemph{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}},
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines are all in the context of a `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}`.
So you can easily overwrite them with a

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  andmore   = {\bbx@cetext{\bbx@cnetal}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
  andothers = {\bbx@cetext{\bbx@cnetal}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
}
```

in your document.

The pairs of lines you mention are in different branches of a `\iftoggle{bbx:ugly}`, so if you need to replicate that as well, go with

```
\iftoggle{bbx:ugly}
  {\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
     andmore   = {\bbx@cetext{\bbx@cnetal}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
     andothers = {\bbx@cetext{\bbx@cnetal}{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
   }}
  {\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
     andmore   = {\bbx@cetext{\bbx@cnetal}{\mkbibemph{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}},
     andothers = {\bbx@cetext{\bbx@cnetal}{\mkbibemph{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}},
   }}
```